# What is the difference between animating Constraints or Transform?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a rather complex animation, using UIViewPropertyAnimator, where I have the need to make precise movements like this one:

[image: animation_gif]

I was wondering what's the difference if I achieve this while animating the constraints, or animating the transform?

I achieved, what you see in the gif, using transform animations. But I got curious, and I got few more screens like this to animate so I wanted to know if there is a preferred way, or any 'animation rules'.

I'm mostly curious if there is a performance difference, but I'd also like to hear if someone got stuck using one of the mentioned ways.

Comment: Use the tool that fits the job. We don't know what your code looks like so this would be opinion based.. However, you can actually do both transformations and constraint animations as long as you achieve the desired effect. There's no performance difference. However, there'd likely be calculations using transformations and having to keep references to constraints if using constraints..

Comment: @Brandon This is what I wanted to hear. Thanks. I don't need help with the code.